# Must declare the scalar variable "@useridaUPDATE"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
sqlqrystrng = "UPDATE temp_user_details set user_name = @username, user_email = @useremail, user_contact = @usercontact, user_address=@useraddress WHERE user_id = @userida"
sqlqrystrng2 = "UPDATE user_type set user_password = @userpassword where user_id = @useridb"
string_cnct = sqlqrystrng & sqlqrystrng2

conn.open

cmd = New SqlCommand(string_cnct, conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@userida"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@useridb"

cmd.Parameters.Item("@userida").Value = struserid
cmd.Parameters.Item("@useridb").Value = struserid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlqrystrng = "UPDATE temp_user_details set user_name = @username, user_email = 
useremail, user_contact = @usercontact, user_address=@useraddress WHERE user_id = 
userida"
sqlqrystrng2 = " UPDATE user_type set user_password = @userpassword where user_id = @useridb"
string_cnct = sqlqrystrng  & sqlqrystrng2
conn.open
cmd = New SqlCommand(string_cnct, conn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@userida"
cmd.Parameters.Add(cmd.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "@useridb"
cmd.Parameters.Item("@userida").Value = struserid
cmd.Parameters.Item("@useridb").Value = struserid
```

You need to add space before **Update** in second string

Comment: Must Declare the scalar variable @cname... How to solve here                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test_1 (cn,ad,img) VALUES (@cname,@cadd, @cimg)"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = conn


            Dim UploadedImage__2 As New SqlParameter("@ImageData", SqlDbType.Image, imageSize.Length)
            UploadedImage__2.Value = imageSize
            cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage__2)
            conn.Open()
            Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()